# when i update my database it wont update and the datas turns to 1.. literally 1

Tags: php, database, mysqli

So I want to update my data in database, and I wanna make sure that the row it updates (which is the last name) is the same as the one logged in. I did is this:

'data' is the name of the table where the logged in last name is to be found, 'ict' is the table where the grades is in and another last name to so that i can compare if they're the same and update that row.

After I input the datas and confirm it, it says "Successfully Inserted" but the data doesn't get updated and it turns to `1`.

This is my code:

```
<?php
include("sq.php");

$a21st =  isset(($_POST['a21st']));
$a21st2 =  isset(($_POST['a21st2']));
$entre =  isset(($_POST['entre']));
$entre2 =  isset(($_POST['entre2']));
$pe3 =  isset(($_POST['pe3']));
$pe32 =  isset(($_POST['pe32']));
$a1 = isset(($_POST['a1']));
$a12 = isset(($_POST['a12']));
$a2 = isset(($_POST['a2']));
$a22 = isset(($_POST['a22']));
$fil = isset(($_POST['fil']));
$fil2 = isset(($_POST['fil2']));
$mil = isset(($_POST['mil']));
$mil2 = isset(($_POST['mil2']));
$contem = isset(($_POST['contem']));
$contem2 = isset(($_POST['contem2']));
$physci = isset(($_POST['physci']));
$physci2 = isset(($_POST['physci2']));
$pe4 = isset(($_POST['pe4']));
$pe42 = isset(($_POST['pe42']));
$reaspro = isset(($_POST['reaspro']));
$reaspro2 = isset(($_POST['reaspro2']));
$a3 = isset(($_POST['a3']));
$a32 = isset(($_POST['a32']));
$a4 = isset(($_POST['a4']));
$a42 = isset(($_POST['a42']));
$immers = isset(($_POST['immers']));
$immers2 = isset(($_POST['immers2']));


if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
         die('Connect Error('. mysqli_connect_errno().')'. mysqli_connect_error());
     } else {

$SELECT =("SELECT * FROM data");
      $result = mysqli_query($db,$SELECT);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $last =  $row['last'];

$UPDATE = "UPDATE `ict` SET a21st = $a21st, a21st2 = $a21st2, entre= $entre, entre2 = $entre2, pe3 = $pe3, pe32 = $pe32, a1 = $a1, a12 = $a12, a2 = $a2, a22 = $a22, fil = $fil, fil2 = $fil2, mil = $mil, mil2 = $mil2, contem = $contem, contem2 = $contem2, physci = $physci, physci2 = $physci2, pe4 = $pe4, pe42 = $pe42, reaspro = $reaspro, reaspro2 = $reaspro2, a3 = $a3, a32 = $a32, a4 = $a4, a42 = $a42, immers = $immers, immers2 = $immers2 WHERE last = '".$last."'";


        if (mysqli_query($db,$UPDATE)){

    $message = "Successfully Inputted!!";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
        }else {
            echo "Error: <br>". $db->error;
            }
     }
$db->close();$db
```

Answer (score 3):

`isset` returns `true` if the value exists, which translates to 1 in a numeric context, which is probably not what you meant. Instead, you need to get the value itself. E.g.:

```
$a21st =  isset($_POST['a21st']) ? $_POST['a21st'] : null;
```